# Trocar cor do item selecionado - select > option

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte `select`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível trocar a cor azul dele para uma que eu queira aplicar, vermelho por exemplo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elementos `SELECT` são renderizados pelo sistema operacional, não HTML. Você não pode mudar essa cor azul, porque ela é padrão do SO.

"A alternativa é usar bibliotecas que customizam o select, geralmente transformado-os em dropdowns e outros (Exemplo: bootstrap select - [silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select))."

Mas voce pode mudar algumas coisas sem usar dropdowns:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.onchange = function () {
    select.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
}
```

```css
.redText {
    background-color:#F00;
}
.greenText {
    background-color:#0F0;
}
.blueText {
    background-color:#00F;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" class="greenText">
    <option class="greenText" value="apple" >Apple</option>
    <option class="redText"   value="banana" >Banana</option>
    <option class="blueText" value="grape" >Grape</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A alternativa é usar bibliotecas que customizam o `select`, geralmente transformado-os em `dropdowns` e outros (Exemplo: bootstrap select - http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

Comment: Eric, dá uma olhada no exemplo que eu coloquei, e veja algumas das mudanças que voce pode fazer.

Comment: Mas, perceba que o AZUL continua, porque ele é padrão do Sistema Operacional.

Comment: Entendi, Paulo. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: E obrigado, Eduardo, pela sugestão.